# Displaying an image - Error: incompatible types: ParseObject cannot be converted to ParseFile

Tags: java, android, image, parse-platform, fragment

I want to retrieve and display a file type data - photo - from Parse database. In another fragment, that I used the below method, I didn't have any problems with displaying the photo that it was a column of the ParseUser object.

Right now, I have a simple object, but I am getting the following error in my code before even run it:

> Error:(114, 73) error: incompatible types: ParseObject cannot be
>   converted to ParseFile

The error refers to this line: `prof_photo = (ParseFile)shop.get("photo");`

---

```
String name = null;
if (getArguments() != null) {
    if (getArguments().getString("name") != null) {
        name = getArguments().getString("name");
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> shop = ParseQuery.getQuery("Shop");
        shop.whereEqualTo("name", name);

        shop.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    ParseFile prof_photo = null;
                    try {
                        prof_photo = (ParseFile)shop.get("photo");
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (prof_photo != null) {
                        prof_photo.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    // data has the bytes for the resume
                                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                    photo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                } else {
                                    // something went wrong
                                    String message = "Something went wrong with displaying the photo!";
                                    Toast.makeText(DisplayShopFragment.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        photo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shop);
                    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:(114, 73) error: incompatible types: ParseObject cannot be
>   converted to ParseFile

Because `shop` is `ParseQuery` of `ParseObject` instead of `ParseFile`. so get method of `shop` return `ParseObject` :

```
ParseObject prof_obj = (ParseObject)scoreList.get(0);
prof_photo = (ParseFile)prof_obj.get("photo");
```

Comment: I tried that and I got an error : `Error:(119, 51) error: cannot find symbol method getDataInBackground(<anonymous GetDataCallback>)` for the line `prof_photo.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {`

Comment: There is no problem before compiling it. I have to do something else before check if I can display the image. I will be back in the post if I can't display it. So thank you for now.

Comment: @marialena: ok try it if any issue then i will try to help and one more suggestion  you are getting List of images from server? so will probably need to use `for` loop to get all images. Thanks:)

Comment: I have only one image because I didn't know how to save multiple images, but I will have it in my mind if I will try to do it.

Comment: @marialena:try it because you can save all images in same way as you are saving one image.

Comment: Okay so I guess I only find a way for multiple choosing from gallery and taking multiple pictures from camera. I will find it. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69755/discussion-between-marialena-and--k).

Comment: @marialena: are you there?